# Circle Image Scope in Iphone Mobile Application ( Xamarin.Ios / C# )

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

i cant seem to find out how to get circle images. whether its a photo selected from gallery, id like it to fit in a scope that shows on the screen and the picture comes circle shaped on the app, instead of the default rectangle or square shaped photo. instagram twitter facebook and linkedIN etc do this. can someone point me in the right direction to maybe look at a plugin, a name of a method i can call,  or a link or code thatll help me accomplish this

Comment: Did you check [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/elegant-circle-images-in-xamarin-forms/) out?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following code :

```
  UIImageView imageView = new UIImageView(new CGRect( 10,10,200,200 ));// Make sure the width and height are equal
  imageView.Image =UIImage.FromBundle(" xxx.png ");
  imageView.Layer.MasksToBounds = true; //It is important
  imageView.Layer.CornerRadius = 100;  //Set the value to half of the width(height)
  View.AddSubview(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following link to implement the round image/circle image functionality:

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ImageCirclePlugin

I have used this in my Xamarin application and it's working without any issues.

Hope this helps you.